# Unix mailx sending zip as a .txt?

Tags: unix, mailx

I am trying to send myself a zip file from a server using mailx -s "my subject" myemail@email < myzip,zip.

However, upon receipt I get the file name as noname, and opening it up it opens it as a text file; with garbled Unicode (I assume since that is the content of the zip). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. mutt -s "subject line" email -a zip.zip < messageBodyThatHasToBeAfileFOrSomeReason